# jQuery script not working after appending dynamic values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am appending values from an array of objects to a div tag. The append just works fine, but the click event on the appended HTML elements are not working

```
let lists = [{name : "one", desc : "test"}, {name : "two", desc : "desc"}]   
 for(let a in lists) 
                $('#list').append('<div class="listing"><li id="' + lists[a].name +'" data-list-name="'+ lists[a].name +'"><h3>'+lists[a].name +'</h3></li><span class="view-more"></span><div class="view-more-container"><p class="list-text"><b>'+lists[a].desc +'</b></p></div></div>');
```

Here the value is appended as expected but click function on the class view-more is not working after appending. it works for direct values and doesn't work for appended one

Comment: I think the code has typo, for(let item in a) , you don;t have lists

Comment: `lists` is undefined, and you have two different `let a` that conflict with each other...

Comment: it was a typo. I corrected thanks. I will go through the link

Comment: That just works

Answer (score 0):

Small error in variable declaration, name is missing

```js
 let lists = [{name : "one", desc : "test"}, {name : "two", desc : "desc"}]   
     for(let a in lists) 
        $('#list').append('<div class="listing"><li id="' + lists[a].name +'" data-list-name="'+ lists[a].name +'"><h3>'+lists[a].name +'</h3></li><span class="view-more"></span><div class="view-more-container"><p class="list-text"><b>'+lists[a].desc +'</b></p></div></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it was typo. I missed to note. Thanks.